# subdir.mk and eclipse cdt

Tags: c++, eclipse, eclipse-cdt

I have a project, in which i use the eclipse cdt on linux, its build chain, and "externalal builder", along with generated makefiles automatically checked.

in settings-cross G++ compiler-includes - i have included libraries A,B,C, both in release and debug mode - but for some reason library C is not included in the g++ call under the -I option.

It seems that the problem is that the subdir.mk files is not being updated with last library added, C. I have tried to be extra sure, and i don't see any other different settings between the debug and release mode.

Does any one know of any idea to fix this? I tried deleted both the Release and Debug directories, and then rebuilding - but still the subdir.mk file is not generated properly.

Comment: I'm having the same problem. Did you manage to resolve this?

Comment: Sorry - I remember the nightmarish problem, but not how i solved it. I know that I had some problem which took me a while to figure out in which the order of the libraries included in the eclipse -L window mattered (which i guess is a general c++ linker thing) - But I don't think it's relevant to this problem. I might have simply started a new project and moved all the files. Or maybe I found some other solution on the net. Sorry, can't help you more than that.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve this problem by deleting the faulty Build Configuration and then re-creating it based on the working one.